# Adding and Removing Event Listeners in Cocos 2D-X 3.2

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to implement an easy way to enable and disable a Touch listener within my class. I tried writing a method within my class:

```
void HelloWorld::setTouchEnabled(bool enabled)
{
    if (enabled)
    {
        auto _touchListener = EventListenerTouchAllAtOnce::create();
        _touchListener->onTouchesBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchesBegan, this);
        _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(_touchListener, this);

    }
    else if (!enabled)
    {
        _eventDispatcher->removeEventListener(_touchListener);
    }

}
```

I was hoping to be able to then call `setTouchEnabled(true)` or `setTouchEnabled(false)` from within any other methods in this class. However, this does not work since `_touchListener` is released at the end of the function. When I tried to declare `EventListener *_touchListener` in my header file, I received an error in XCode on this line:

```
_touchListener->onTouchesBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchesBegan, this);
```

The error said that no member named `onTouchesBegan` exists in `cocos2d::EventListener`.

I'm assuming there must be an easy way to do this.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_To_Subclass_Sprite_And_Add_Event_Listeners. I think you will get a few compiler errors for 3.2 due to some class renaming but these are an easy fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn C++ first:)

Define `_touchListener` in your header file first, as a member of `HelloWorld`. Then modify your cpp file:

```
void HelloWorld::setTouchEnabled(bool enabled)
{
    if (enabled)
    {
        _touchListener = EventListenerTouchAllAtOnce::create();
        _touchListener->retain();
        _touchListener->onTouchesBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchesBegan, this);
        _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(_touchListener, this);

    }
    else if (!enabled)
    {
        _eventDispatcher->removeEventListener(_touchListener);
        _touchListener->release();
        _touchListener = nullptr;
    }

}
```